# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer + PropertiesFactoryBean only resolving location properties

Tags: java, spring, properties

I am having trouble getting PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to work in my current configuration.  Given the following block of code in my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="myProperties" 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <!-- Order matters, last one to create a property wins! -->
            <value>classpath:default.properties</value>
            <value>file:${MYAPP_PROPERTIES_LOCATION:badurl}/application.properties</value>
            <value>file:${user.home}/developer.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="myProperties"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Then in the default.properties files I have the following (these are test properties):

```
property1=prop1val
property2=${property1}
```

What works: the propertyConfigurer correctly resolves both the environment variable MYAPP_PROPERTIES_LOCATION and the System variable user.home.  However, then the final properties object is created by the factory bean, the resulting properties are  **[property1=prop1val, property2=${property1}]**.

**With this configuration, how can I get the properties inside the myProperties bean to resolve their placeholders??**  I have done plenty of research to include tracing through the spring code - and I can see how and why this isn't being done.  I'm hoping there is some setting I'm just missing!  This is my first post so be easy on me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have proper configuration of spring and the property files. That why you are being able to read the data from the file. **Everything is proper with what spring is doing too**, let me explain a bit more....

As you told below is your property file,

```
property1=prop1val
property2=${property1}
```

Remember, it is a pretty text file with key value pairs and it can not take variables. Here, if you are intended to copy the value of `property1` to `property2` dynamically it is not going to happen. That is not the way we are supposed to use a property file.

Property file is supposed to be simple text file with key-value pairs. So, keep the keys atomic so that you can construct the required data logically from the application or inside your `applicationcontext.xml` file.

Comment: What I really wanted to accomplish here is to have a log.dir property that was relative to a base.dir where base.dir could be set in any of these files.  Then Log4J is configured using a listener based on this directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using `PropertiesFactoryBean`. Can you please try just the following (Not sure if you already tried it and  any issues you faced)

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"  
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
  <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <!-- Order matters, last one to create a property wins! -->
            <value>classpath:default.properties</value>
            <value>file:${MYAPP_PROPERTIES_LOCATION:badurl}/application.properties</value>
            <value>file:${user.home}/developer.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: In this configuration, how do I reference the merged properties bean?

Comment: you mean `property2` ! Not sure what you mean by merged Properties bean ?

Comment: I mean, in my current configuration I access my merged properties like this: 
`@Autowired
@Qualifier("myProperties")
private Properties props;`

Then I can access property2 saying `props.getProperty("property2");`  

In your case I don't have a `PropertiesFactoryBean` to reference.

Comment: I guess I see your problem. You are accessing `property2` via `props.getProperty("property2")` and not in a standard way using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. The resolution of properties of type `property2=${property1}` where `property1` is another property is done by `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and by using `props.getProperty("property2")` you are bypassing `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` hence `${property1}` is not resolved to appropriate value. If you use `property2` via standard spring wiring, it will resolve to appropriate value.